# Getting document from a library based on GUID in SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, document, stsadm, guid

I have a GUID which belongs to an item (probably document or some folder, not confirmed that's why I am looking for this solution) inside a particular library. Is it possible to get document name etc. using GUID via STSADM?

Or is it possible to do using custom solution? SharePoint is 2007.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you're referring to listitem Unique ID.

As per quick glance at the [list of STSADM operations](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2008/03/15/complete-reference-of-all-stsadm-operations-with-parameters-in-moss-2007-sp1/) this cannot be done.

Your options to fetch the item are:

- Set up powershell on the farm ([one of the guides](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/05/how-to-use-powershell-with-sharepoint-2007.html)) and write a PS script
- Write custom solution using SSOM

Answer (score 0):

I went on to directly query (this is officially not recommended by Microsoft) table "AllDocs" which contain all documents. The first column "Id" in this table contain GUID.